# Como fazer uma consulta com dados de duas tabelas relacionadas?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho esse caso a baixo:

```
 (Tabelas)
 cidades:   id, nome_cidade,local
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 |  id    |  nome_cidade   |    Local      |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 |   1    | Rio de Janeiro |    Centro     |
 |   2    | São Paulo      |    Centro     |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+

 (dados)
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 |  NOME  |     origem     |    destino    |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 | Paulo  |        1       |       2       |
 | Rafael |        2       |       1       |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
```

Gostaria que me retornasse assim:

```
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 |  NOME  |     origem     |    destino    |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 | Paulo  | Rio de Janeiro | São Paulo     |
 | Rafael | São Paulo      | Rio de Janiro |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
```

Pegando os ids da tabela cidades e e retornando com os nomes delas.
Estou usando este código abaixo:

```
 SELECT d.*, c.nome_cidade  FROM dados d
 JOIN cidades c ON d.cidade = c.id
 JOIN cidades s ON d.cidade2 = s.id
```

Nesse caso está me repetindo assim

```
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 |   NOME |     origem     |    destino    |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
 | Paulo  | Rio de Janeiro | Rio de Janiro |
 | Rafael | São Paulo      | São Paulo     |
 +--------+----------------+---------------+
```

Oque devo esta fazendo errado?

Tentei também assim mais não deu:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dados 
 INNER JOIN cidades ON (dados.cidade = cidade.id) 
 INNER JOIN cidades ON (dados.cidade2 = cidade.id)


 $cidade1 = $linha["cidade"];
 $cidade2 = $linha["cidade2"];";
```

Comment: Quando você diz que está repetindo você fala dos nomes das colunas `CIDADE` e `CIDADE 2` do resutado?

Comment: Desculpa já corrigi la..  É Coluna Origem e Destino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você seguiu o caminho certo na sua query mas só está selecionando o nome da cidade de *origem* (`c.nome_cidade`).

Você pode fazer assim:

```
 SELECT d.nome, c1.nome_cidade AS origem, c2.nome_cidade AS destino  FROM dados d
  JOIN cidades c1 ON d.origem = c1.id 
  JOIN cidades c2 ON d.destino = c2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei bem onde você está confuso, mas a query deveria ser esta:

```
SELECT
  dados.nome,
  origem.nome_cidade as origem,
  destino.nome_cidade as destino
FROM dados
  INNER JOIN cidades origem
  ON origem.id = dados.origem
  INNER JOIN cidades destino
  ON destino.id = dados.destino
ORDER BY dados.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7806a2/2